# ¿Como puedo crear un procedimiento (SUB) pero con n parametros?

Tags: vba

Lo que quiero es crear un procedimiento pero que este reciba n parametros (osea que se desconoce cuantos parametros ceran)
solo he logrado algo hacerlo conociendo la cantidad de parametros

```
Sub Actualizar_Ribbon(ByVal boton1 As String, Optional boton2 As String)
    UNIVidaTab.InvalidateControl (boton1)
    If boton2 <> Empty Then
        UNIVidaTab.InvalidateControl (boton2)
    End If
End Sub
```

lo que tengo en mente es algo asi aclaro que no he resuelto aun como hacer referencia ha todos los parametros y en este ejemplo tengo 5 parametros pero aclaro que lo que quiero es que reciba n parametros

```
Sub Actualizar_Ribbon(ByVal boton1 As String, Optional boton2 As String, Optional boton3 As String, Optional boton4 As String, Optional boton5 As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        If boton & i <> Empty Then
            UNIVidaTab.InvalidateControl (boton & i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

les agradeceria mucho si logran ayudarme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes declarar un array variable de parametros mediante [`ParamArray`](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/paramarray.htm), un ejemplo:

```
Sub MiFuncion(ParamArray MiParametros() As Variant)
    Dim Parametro As Variant
    For Each Parametro In MiParametros
      Debug.Print Parametro
   Next Parametro
End Sub

Sub main()
    Call MiFuncion("Hola", "Mundo", 100)
    Call MiFuncion(-1, 100)
End Sub
```

La Salida:

```
Hola
Mundo
 100 
-1 
 100
```

Al tratarse de un array de objetos `Variant` puedes, con cuidado, pasar todo tipo de valores. Tu rutina, finalmente podría quedar así:

```
Sub Actualizar_Ribbon(ParamArray Botones() As Variant)
    Dim Boton As Variant
    For Each Boton In Botones
      UNIVidaTab.InvalidateControl(str(Boton))
   Next Boton
End Sub
```